# data is not saved in mongodb from express using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pug = require('pug');
const db = require('mongoose');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
db.Promise = global.Promise;
var app = express();
var Schema = db.Schema;
var optionsdb = { promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') };

//Conexion a MongoDB
var connection = db.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/project', optionsdb, () => {
  console.log("Base de datos conectada")
});


var conn = db.connection;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function() {
  console.log('opened');
});

// connect to mongo function



//Creacion de la Base de Datos en un JSON
var usuarios = {
      email: String, 
      password: String,
    }

  //no tocar
var db1;

//Model 
var user_schema = new Schema(usuarios);
var User = db.model('User', user_schema);


    //vistas y configuracion
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());





     //peticiones HTTP
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index');
  console.log('Hiciste una peticion GET');
});

app.get('/login', (req,res) => {
  res.render('login');
  console.log('Entraste al Login');
});

app.get('/register', (req,res) => {
  res.render('register');
  console.log('Entraste al Register');
});


app.post('/register', (req,res) => {

   var datos = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      }).save( (err,data) => {
        if(err){
          return err
        } else {
          console.log("datos enviados")
          res.render('bienvenido')
        }   
    })  

});
//Puerto en el que se va a escuchar el servidor
app.listen(80, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('Servidor iniciado correctamente');
});
```

and I don't know why, when I do a POST require, this POST petittion:

```
app.post('/register', (req,res) => {
       var datos = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
          }).save( (err,data) => {
            if(err){
              return err
            } else {
              console.log("datos enviados")
              res.render('bienvenido')
            }   
        })
```

12/5000

Nothing happens. The console does not show me any errors. I login but do not send the data, it does not redirect me to the page and it does not show me any errors in console. The page remains loading.

Comment: This is a bit suspect: `app.listen(80` since you should not be able to bind to that port unless running under root. Are you sure the server is actually running?

Comment: Yeah, This console.lgo("Servidor Iniciado Correctamente') Says in English: Server started successfully. I'm seeing in my console that I get the message, besides, I can access the login path, and that's because the server is running. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: why are you trying to connect to db two times using `mongoose` and `MongoClient` it should be one

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Which one do I really need to use?

Comment: you are using mongoose to define your schema so you should use only mongoose

Comment: @ShaishabRoy Ready, I did. But I still have the same problem. When I do the POST request, the data is not saved.

Comment: Try posting with `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost/register` to at least rule out other code that might not be doing this correctly. If you get a response then the problem is actually elsewhere.

Comment: It would help for "clarity" if you removed the `MongoClient` usage from your code since you are actually not using that anywhere. At least it will stop people commenting about it.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I just did it a few minutes ago, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I was talking about removing the code from "this post". I already know it's not the issue. Please run the `curl` command I gave you.

Comment: @NeilLunn It does nothing, it only re-runs the console. :( I'm desperate, I've had the same mistake for two days. :(

Comment: Does nothing means what? No output? There must be some output. Paste the output into your question if you are unsure what it means.

Comment: @NeilLunn No output. I copy from beginning to end. I put it in my console, and it does a re-run.Can we use the chat? Any method to communicate more quickly?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to chat. What does "re-run" mean?

Comment: @NeilLunn, When I put the code that you gave me on the console, I run it, it's as if nothing had happened. Please, text me for Twitter :( user: magodiesan. I'm getting a notice here that says the following: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?